# dynamically built input using MDL does not render correctly

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-design-lite

I have the following code,

```
var loginForm = document.createElement('div');

loginForm.className = 'row';

loginForm.innerHTML = '<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label textfield-demo"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="login" /><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="login">Username</label></div>';

document.getElementById('page-content').appendChild(loginForm);
```

The problem is that since the javascript functions have already ran the input is not styled correctly.

Does anyone what javascript function I need to call to make this work? I tried `MaterialTextfield.prototype.init()` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MDL's upgrading element function. Since you have created the loginForm dynamically, you can upgrade it in scope with

```
    componentHandler.upgradeElement(loginForm);
    //or, componentHandler.upgradeDom(loginForm);
    //however, I suggest using jQuery to upgrade multiple if you are adding more than one
    componentHandler.upgradeElements($('.mdl-textfield').get());
```

This will get all the mdl-textfield objects and upgrade them (if not upgraded before)

Answer (score 2):

I kept digging through the source code and found `componentHandler.upgradeDom()`. When running this function all of the dynamic elements are fixed.